How to get the output variable in a JS stored procedure
I have this stored procedure written in JS:
CREATE
OR REPLACE PROCEDURE STATE_CONFIG.MERGER_BUILDER_GEN(
    "DATA_FACTORY_RUN_ID" VARCHAR(100),
    "DATABASE_ID" VARCHAR(100),
    "LOAD_GROUP" VARCHAR(100),
    "OBJECT_ID" VARCHAR(100),
    "SINK_FILE_LOCATION" VARCHAR(500),
    "SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA" VARCHAR(100),
    "BASE_SCHEMA" VARCHAR(100),
    "TABLE_NAME" VARCHAR(200),
    "BEGINTIME" VARCHAR(500),
    "STAGE_NAME" VARCHAR(200)
) RETURNS VARCHAR(32000) LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT EXECUTE AS CALLER AS '
    var result;
    snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "begin transaction;"});
    var my_sql_command = `SELECT 
        ''` + DATA_FACTORY_RUN_ID + `'' AS DATAFACTORYRUNID
        ,''` + DATABASE_ID + `'' AS DATABASEID
        ,''` + LOAD_GROUP + `'' AS LOADGROUP
        ,''` + OBJECT_ID + `'' AS OBJECTID
        , 0 AS "number of rows inserted"
        , 0 as "number of rows updated"
        ,''` + SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA + `'' AS TARGET_SCHEMA
        ,''` + BASE_SCHEMA + `'' AS SOURCE_SCHEMA
        ,''` + TABLE_NAME + `'' AS TARGET_TABLE
        ,''` + BEGINTIME + `'' AS BEGINTIMESTAMP
        ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS ENDTIMESTAMP
        ,CURRENT_USER() AS USER_NAME 
        ,CURRENT_ROLE() USER_ROLE
        ,''Failed'' as status`;
        var statement1 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: my_sql_command} );
        var result_set1 = statement1.execute();
      result_set1.next();
        var column1 = result_set1.getColumnValue(1);
        var column2 = result_set1.getColumnValue(2);
        var column3 = result_set1.getColumnValue(3);
        var column4 = result_set1.getColumnValue(4);
        var column5 = result_set1.getColumnValue(5);
        var column6 = result_set1.getColumnValue(6);
        var column7 = result_set1.getColumnValue(7);
        var column8 = result_set1.getColumnValue(8);
        var column9 = result_set1.getColumnValue(9);
        var column10 = result_set1.getColumnValue(10);
        var column11 = result_set1.getColumnValue(11);
        var column12 = result_set1.getColumnValue(12);
        var column13 = result_set1.getColumnValue(13);
        var column14 = result_set1.getColumnValue(14);

try {
    var v_sql_stmt = `CREATE OR REPLACE temporary TABLE STATE_CONFIG.vars_of_merger_dyn00 AS 
                    SELECT  
                    COL_NAMES_SELECT    
                    ,REPLACE(listagg (distinct'' nvl(tgt."''||cons.constraint_name||''",''
                    ||CASE  WHEN cons.data_type =''FLOAT'' THEN ''0'' 
                            WHEN cons.data_type LIKE ''NUMBER%'' THEN ''0''
                            WHEN cons.data_type =''DATE'' THEN ''''''1900-12-01''''''
                            WHEN cons.data_type =''TIMESTAMP_NTZ'' THEN ''''''1900-12-01 00:00:00''''''
                            WHEN cons.data_type =''TIME'' THEN ''''''00:00:00''''''
                            ELSE ''-999999'' END||'') = nvl(src."'' 
                            ||cons.constraint_name ||''",''
                    ||CASE  WHEN cons.data_type =''FLOAT'' THEN ''0'' 
                            WHEN cons.data_type LIKE ''NUMBER%'' THEN ''0''
                            WHEN cons.data_type =''DATE'' THEN ''''''1900-12-01''''''
                            WHEN cons.data_type =''TIMESTAMP_NTZ'' THEN ''''''1900-12-01 00:00:00''''''
                            WHEN cons.data_type =''TIME'' THEN ''''''00:00:00''''''
                            ELSE ''-999999'' END  ,'') and \\n'') ||'')'',''-999999'','''''''''''') AS dd
                    ,REPLACE(COL_NAMES_WHEN,''-999999'','''''''''''') AS COL_NAMES_WHEN
                    ,COL_NAMES_SET
                    ,COL_NAMES_INS
                    ,COL_NAMES_INS1
                    FROM (
                    SELECT 
                     InTab.TABLE_NAME              
                    ,listagg ('' cast($''   ||InTab.ORDINAL_POSITION || '' as '' || intab.out_DataType || '') as "'' ||InTab.COLUMN_NAME,''", \\n'') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION asc ) ||''"''  AS Col_Names_select
                    ,listagg ('' nvl(tgt."''  || CASE WHEN intab.CM IS NULL THEN InTab.COLUMN_NAME ELSE NULL end  || ''", ''
                    ||CASE  WHEN intab.out_DataType =''FLOAT'' THEN ''0'' 
                            WHEN intab.out_DataType LIKE ''NUMBER%'' THEN ''0''
                            WHEN intab.out_DataType =''DATE'' THEN ''''''1900-12-01''''''
                            WHEN intab.out_DataType =''TIMESTAMP_NTZ'' THEN ''''''1900-12-01 00:00:00''''''  
                            WHEN intab.out_DataType =''TIME'' THEN ''''''00:00:00'''''' ELSE ''-999999'' END
                    ||'') != nvl(src."'' ||InTab.COLUMN_NAME||''",''||
                      CASE  WHEN intab.out_DataType =''FLOAT'' THEN ''0'' 
                            WHEN intab.out_DataType LIKE ''NUMBER%'' THEN ''0''
                            WHEN intab.out_DataType =''DATE'' THEN ''''''1900-12-01''''''
                            WHEN intab.out_DataType =''TIMESTAMP_NTZ'' THEN ''''''1900-12-01 00:00:00''''''
                            WHEN intab.out_DataType =''TIME'' THEN ''''''00:00:00'''''' ELSE ''-999999'' END
                    ,'') OR\\n'') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION asc ) ||'')'' AS Col_Names_when
                    ,listagg ('' tgt."''  ||CASE WHEN intab.CM IS NULL THEN InTab.COLUMN_NAME ELSE NULL end || ''"= src."'' ||InTab.COLUMN_NAME , ''",\\n'') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION asc ) ||''"'' AS Col_Names_set
                    ,listagg ( ''"''||InTab.COLUMN_NAME,''",\\n'') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION asc ) ||''"'' AS Col_Names_ins
                    ,listagg ( '' src."''  ||InTab.COLUMN_NAME,''",\\n'') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY InTab.ORDINAL_POSITION asc ) ||''"'' AS Col_Names_ins1 
                    ,listagg (ORDINAL_POSITION,'','') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION asc ) ORDINAL_POSITION
                    FROM (
                    SELECT 
                     InTab.TABLE_NAME              
                    ,InTab.COLUMN_NAME
                    ,InTab.ORDINAL_POSITION
                    ,case when intab.data_type = ''NUMBER'' THEN CONCAT(intab.data_type,''('', intab.NUMERIC_PRECISION, '','' ,intab.NUMERIC_SCALE, '')'') ELSE intab.DATA_TYPE END AS out_DataType
                    ,cons.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS CM
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS InTab 
                    LEFT JOIN STATE_CONFIG.pvw_CONSTRAINTS cons ON cons.table_name = intab.table_name AND InTab.COLUMN_NAME = cons.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                    where intab.TABLE_SCHEMA = ''`+ SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA +`''
                    AND intab.TABLE_NAME = ''`+ TABLE_NAME +`''
                    GROUP BY 
                    InTab.TABLE_NAME
                    ,InTab.COLUMN_NAME 
                    ,InTab.COLUMN_NAME
                    ,InTab.ORDINAL_POSITION
                    ,out_DataType
                    ,CONSTRAINT_NAME
                    ORDER BY InTab.TABLE_NAME,InTab.ORDINAL_POSITION ) InTab
                    GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
                    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME,ORDINAL_POSITION
                    ) tt
                    LEFT JOIN STATE_CONFIG.pvw_CONSTRAINTS cons ON cons.table_name = tt.table_name
                    GROUP BY
                    COL_NAMES_SELECT    
                    ,COL_NAMES_WHEN
                    ,COL_NAMES_SET
                    ,COL_NAMES_INS
                    ,COL_NAMES_INS1;` ; 
    
    var rs_clip_name = snowflake.execute ({sqlText: v_sql_stmt});
   
    var my_sql_command1 = `SELECT Col_Names_select,dd,Col_Names_when,Col_Names_set,Col_Names_ins,Col_Names_ins1 FROM STATE_CONFIG.vars_of_merger_dyn00;`; 
    
    var statement2 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: my_sql_command1} );
    var result_set = statement2.execute();
    result_set.next();
    var Col_Names_select = result_set.getColumnValue(1);
    var dd = result_set.getColumnValue(2);
    var Col_Names_when = result_set.getColumnValue(3);
    var Col_Names_set = result_set.getColumnValue(4);
    var Col_Names_ins = result_set.getColumnValue(5);
    var Col_Names_ins1 = result_set.getColumnValue(6);

if (Col_Names_set == ''"'') 
{ 
var my_sql_command2 = `MERGE INTO `+ SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA +`.`+ TABLE_NAME +` AS tgt
USING 
( select
`+ Col_Names_select +`
from 
@STATE_CONFIG.GENERIC_STAGE` + SINK_FILE_LOCATION + ` (file_format =>  ''STATE_CONFIG.CSV'')
GROUP BY 
`+ Col_Names_ins +`)
AS src

ON ( `+ dd +`
     )

WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT ( `+ Col_Names_ins +`)
VALUES 
(`+ Col_Names_ins1 +`); `; 
    var rs_clip_name2 = snowflake.execute ({sqlText: my_sql_command2});

snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: `INSERT INTO STATE_CONFIG.OBJECTEXTRACTLOG 
(DATAFACTORYRUNID, DATABASEID, LOADGROUP, OBJECTID, "number of rows inserted", "number of rows updated", TARGET_SCHEMA, SOURCE_SCHEMA, TARGET_TABLE ,, BEGINTIMESTAMP, ENDTIMESTAMP, USER_NAME, USER_ROLE, STATUS, MESSAGE)
 SELECT ''` + DATA_FACTORY_RUN_ID + `'' AS DATAFACTORYRUNID, ''` + DATABASE_ID + `'' AS DATABASEID, ''` + LOAD_GROUP + `'' AS LOADGROUP, ''` + OBJECT_ID + `'' AS OBJECTID, "number of rows inserted", 0 AS "number of rows updated", ''` + SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA + `'' AS TARGET_SCHEMA,''` + BASE_SCHEMA + `'' AS SOURCE_SCHEMA  , ''` + TABLE_NAME + `'' AS TARGET_TABLE  , ''` + BEGINTIME + `'' AS BEGINTIMESTAMP  , DATEADD(''hour'',  -5, sysdate()), CURRENT_USER() ,CURRENT_ROLE(),''done'' as status ,'''' AS message
        FROM TABLE (RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID(-1)));`} ).execute();

} 
else 
{
var my_sql_command2 = `MERGE INTO `+ SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA +`.`+ TABLE_NAME +` AS tgt
USING 
( select
`+ Col_Names_select +`
from 
@STATE_CONFIG.GENERIC_STAGE` + SINK_FILE_LOCATION + ` (file_format =>  ''STATE_CONFIG.CSV'')
GROUP BY 
`+ Col_Names_ins +`)
AS src
ON ( `+ dd +`
     )
WHEN MATCHED
AND `+ Col_Names_when +`
THEN UPDATE SET
`+ Col_Names_set +`
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT ( `+ Col_Names_ins +`)
VALUES 
(`+ Col_Names_ins1 +`); `; 
    var rs_clip_name2 = snowflake.execute ({sqlText: my_sql_command2});

snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: `INSERT INTO STATE_CONFIG.OBJECTEXTRACTLOG 
(DATAFACTORYRUNID, DATABASEID, LOADGROUP, OBJECTID, "number of rows inserted", "number of rows updated", TARGET_SCHEMA, SOURCE_SCHEMA, TARGET_TABLE , BEGINTIMESTAMP, ENDTIMESTAMP, USER_NAME, USER_ROLE, STATUS, MESSAGE)
 SELECT ''` + DATA_FACTORY_RUN_ID + `'' AS DATAFACTORYRUNID, ''` + DATABASE_ID + `'' AS DATABASEID, ''` + LOAD_GROUP + `'' AS LOADGROUP, ''` + OBJECT_ID + `'' AS OBJECTID, "number of rows inserted", "number of rows updated", ''` + SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA + `'' AS TARGET_SCHEMA, ''` + BASE_SCHEMA + `'' AS SOURCE_SCHEMA  , ''` + TABLE_NAME + `'' AS TARGET_TABLE  , ''` + BEGINTIME + `'' AS BEGINTIMESTAMP  , DATEADD(''hour'',  -5, sysdate()), CURRENT_USER() ,CURRENT_ROLE(),''done'' as status ,'''' AS message
        FROM TABLE (RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID(-1)));`} ).execute();   

}
     snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "commit;"} );
    result = "Succeeded" + my_sql_command2 ;
} catch (err) {
  snowflake.execute({
      sqlText: `insert INTO STATE_CONFIG.OBJECTEXTRACTLOG  VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)` 
      ,binds: [column1, column2, column3 ,column4 , column5 , column6 ,column7 , column8 ,column9 ,column10 ,column11 ,column12,column13, column14, err.code + " | State: " + err.state + "\\n  Message: " + err.message + "\\nStack Trace:\\n" + err.stackTraceTxt ]
      });
     snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "commit;"} );
     return ''Failed.'' + my_sql_command2 ;
}
return result;

';

I have this table:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE STATE_CONFIG.OBJECTEXTRACTLOG 
(
    LOG_ID NUMBER(38, 0) AUTOINCREMENT START 1 INCREMENT 1 ORDER,
    DATAFACTORYRUNID VARCHAR(1000),
    DATABASEID NUMBER(38, 0),
    LOADGROUP NUMBER(38, 0),
    OBJECTID NUMBER(38, 0),
    "number of rows inserted" NUMBER(38, 0),
    "number of rows updated" NUMBER(38, 0),
    TARGET_SCHEMA VARCHAR(255),
    -- Changed from OBJECTSCHEMA to TARGET_SCHEMA
    SOURCE_SCHEMA VARCHAR(255),
    -- New column
    TARGET_TABLE VARCHAR(100),
    BEGINTIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9),
    -- New column
    ENDTIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9),
    USER_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    USER_ROLE VARCHAR(100),
    STATUS VARCHAR(50),
    MESSAGE VARCHAR(4000)
);

I can't seem to figure out how to put the SQL query output in the column MESSAGE. I've tried defining the output and calling it in the SQL statement, however the result is only [object Object] or undefined. I suspect that the variable is empty when I call it or I'm not calling it properly or not defining it properly.
I want the SQL query that's used to insert the records from my_sql_command2 in the column MESSAGE. I may rename this column to query but I want to just get something working before I focus on that.

Hi - “sql query output” implies the result from running the query whereas “sql query” implies the text of the sql query - can you confirm which one you are trying to save to the table? Assuming it’s the query then which query in your script are you trying to write to the table? What’s stopping you just including in your insert statement the variable that holds this sql statement? For example, … CURRENT_ROLE(),''done'' as status , my_sql_command2 AS message

sorry. shoul've clarified. i want the sql query -- the text of the sql that's used. not the output. although, i wouldnt mind the output either

Ok, so what’s stopping you writing my_sql_command2 to your table?

I was about to say that. I believe for this, he said the output is [object object].
